# Check to See if a Word is in a Sentence

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame containing sentences like below:

```
c("Animation", "Comedy", "Family")
```

How can I check to see if there is any special word such as "Animation" in the sentence?

Comment: `grep` and `%in%` will find instances of a string in a vector.  I know the former supports regex, not sure about the latter

Comment: Try `"Animation" %in% sentence`. This gives a logical vector.

Comment: Something like `grep(paste0(c("Animation", "Comedy", "Family"), collapse = "|"), YourSentences)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the data for us to work with:

```
somedat <- c("Animation", "Comedy", "Family", "Animation2")
```

If you only want to know if the column contain that exact word, you can use:

```
"Animation" %in% somedat
# returns TRUE
```

If you want to get the index of the word (or row number) if it's in the column:

```
grep(pattern="Animation", somedat)
# returns 1 4
```

If you want to get the word returned to you:

```
grep(pattern="Animation", somedat, value=T)
# returns [1] "Animation"  "Animation2"
```

Comment: exact matching can be also obtained by `grep(pattern="\\bAnimation\\b", somedat)`. By the way the question is to find several words in a sentence, not a word in a vector of words

Comment: You're right, you can also use regex matching if you like. I first thought that too, but then re-reading the OP's question and he was quite specific: I have a column in my data frame containing sentences like below: `c("Animation", "Comedy", "Family")` so I have to adjust my prior assumption and gave him what is most likely useful to the OP